# Finding the probability that a sampled set contains at least one element of a subset

Tags: probability, distributions

Given a population of `n` items, there are `m` (such that `m < n`) items within that population that are interesting (each element from the set of interesting items is also a member of the larger population). If I take a random sample of `s` items from the population of `n` items, what is the probability that my sample will contain at least one element that is interesting?

Comment: What is the chance that your sample contains *no* interesting elements?

Comment: @whuber the sample is random and uniform, so the "chance that the sample has no interesting elements" is essentially what I'm trying to find.

Comment: My point is that reframing the question in this way makes it exceptionally easy to answer.

Comment: @whuber So I guess the probability of not picking a single element that's interesting is `m/n`. The probability of picking the second element also not in the set would be `m/n-1`, and so on. So for the whole set I guess it should be `m/n*m/n-1*...m/n-s`. Is there a nice way to generalize this?